# In C#, How can I serialize Queue<>? (.Net 2.0)

Tags: c#, .net, generics, serialization, .net-2.0

At the XmlSerializer constructor line the below causes an InvalidOperationException which also complains about not having a default accesor implemented for the generic type.

```
Queue<MyData> myDataQueue = new Queue<MyData>();

// Populate the queue here


XmlSerializer mySerializer =
  new XmlSerializer(myDataQueue.GetType());    

StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter("myData.xml");
mySerializer.Serialize(myWriter, myDataQueue);
myWriter.Close();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It would be easier (and more appropriate IMO) to serialize the *data* from the queue - perhaps in a flat array or `List<T>`. Since `Queue<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, you should be able to use:

```
List<T> list = new List<T>(queue);
```

Comment: You could also use queue.ToList()

Comment: I'd like to know more about the "more appropriate" comment you made.

Comment: @chakrit - only with .NET 3.5, but yes.

Comment: This doesn't really help if you serialize a class that contains Queue<T>... Unless you are happy to XmlIgnore the Queue and ensure you have a List<T> field holding a copy of the data... Or are there better ways?

Answer (score 1):

Not all parts of the framework are designed for XML serialization.  You'll find that dictionaries also are lacking in the serialization department.

A queue is pretty trivial to implement.  You can easily create your own that also implements IList so that it will be serializable.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the built in serialization you need to play by its rules, which means default ctor, and public get/set properties for the members you want to serialize (and presumably deserialize )
on the data type you want to serialize (MyData)

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had a dynamic queue and i had to save and load the state of this one.

Using Newtonsoft.Json:

```
List<dynamic> sampleListOfRecords = new List<dynamic>();
Queue<dynamic> recordQueue = new Queue<dynamic>();
//I add data to queue from a sample list
foreach(dynamic r in sampleListOfRecords)
{
     recordQueue.Enqueue(r);
}

//Serialize
File.WriteAllText("queue.json",
     JsonConvert.SerializeObject(recordQueue.ToList(), Formatting.Indented));
//Deserialize
List<dynamic> data = 
     JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(File.ReadAllText("queue.json"));
```