# Convert Queue<T> properties to List<T> on JSON serialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, unity-game-engine, json.net

I'm using the JSON.Net ([here](http://james.newtonking.com/json)) lib to do some (de/)serialization. But the version of JSON.Net I'm using (think it's modified to work with Unity3D - on phones that is) can't serialize Queue, but can without problem serialize List.

So the following class serialize properly (the string will be be containing list items):

```
public class SomeClassList
{
 List<SomeOtherClass> m_Stuff = new List<SomeOtherClass>();
 public List<SomeOtherClass> Stuff
 {
  get{return m_Stuff;}
 }
}
```

But this will not:

```
public class SomeClassQueue
{
 Queue<SomeOtherClass> m_Stuff = new Queue<SomeOtherClass>();
 public Queue<SomeOtherClass> Stuff
 {
  get{return m_Stuff;}
 }
}
```

Example:

```
.
.
.
SomeClassList someClassList = new SomeClassList()
SomeClassQueue someClassQueue = new SomeClassQueue()
```

Doing this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someClassList)
```

will return: {"Stuff":[SomeOtherClass, SomeOtherClass, SomeOtherClass]} (Where 'SomeOtherClass' are really the fields and it's data of SomeOtherClass

Doing this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SomeClassQueue)
```

will return:

```
 {"Stuff":[]}
```

Because it fails to read the Queues entities.

I'm wondering how I can use the IContractResolver or inherit from DefaultContractResolver to convert from Queue to a List on serialization (so that it can be read properly) and turn it back to a Queue on deserialization.

Comment: @Daniel A. White: Thank you for your edit, but isn't the question too "general" when not specifying which library is used?

Comment: The tag you added is enough; no need to add it in title.

Comment: Tags are better in the tags field. It keeps the title clean and more interesting.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that!

Comment: maybe you can show us what you tried so far

Comment: Does the order of the queue matter when serializing?

Comment: (At)Carsten, I haven't been able to test anything at all because I can't understand how the IContractResolver works. The only examples I've found deal with changing a property name on serialization.

@Yuval Itzchakov, not necessarily, but preferably! You had an idea in mind?

Answer (score -1):

There was a similar stackoverflow question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/310171/2631842).

*Since Queue implements IEnumerable, you should be able to use:*

```
List<T> list = new List<T>(queue);

#likewise
Queue queue = new Queue<T>(list);
```

and vice versa

else you may also use 
 
    `queue.ToList()`

Comment: I guess he don't want to change his code/representation just because the serializer cannot handle it (a very reasonable idea)

Comment: As Carsten is saying, I don't wanna change my class just because I can't serialize the property. I wanna use the ContractResolver to do the thing you're suggesting. :(